# What's the best way to change filename extensions in .NET?

Tags: .net-4.0, .net

I've got a thumbnailer which scans a given directory and generates thumbnails for the image files it finds.

I've got a nice generic way of loading the images I find which match allowed file extensions (`bmp`, `jpg`, `png`, etc.) but... I want to write all thumbnail files as `png`.

What I don't know is how to conveniently extract the filename without extension and stick a `.png` on the end before outputting my image...

```
    For Each File In SourceFileList
        Dim FileInfo = New FileInfo(File)
        Dim ThumbFilename = String.Format("{0}\Thumb_{1}", TargetDir, FileInfo.Name) '<-- How do I set the correct name here?
        Dim Thumb = Thumbnailer.Thumbnail(FileInfo.FullName, 100)
        Thumb.Save(ThumbFilename, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    Next
```

I'm aware I can use `Split` and various other string manipulations but all seem a little clunky. Is there a best-practice way of doing this? Something in `System.IO`?

(I would never have thought 10 years ago that `split` would e too clunky - How times have changed!)

Comment: @Michael Petrotta - Thank you for your edit to improve the title but I'd prefer to leave the "Thanks in advance..." in the question unless it breaks any specific guidelines? I like being polite to those who are giving up their time to help me...

Comment: It does. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks' and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts), and a number of related discussions on the right side of that page. I appreciate your sentiments, but I'd suggest that writing good questions (which yours is) is a much better way of showing politeness and courtesy.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta point taken, thanks for the tip. I'll undo my change to put it back in now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`Path.ChangeExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension.aspx).
You should also take a look at the rest of the `Path` class; it's a very useful but little-known class.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need. Let me try it and I'll get back to you

Comment: That was perfect, thanks - Look like there's a new namespace I need to explore :)

Comment: `Path` is a class, not a namespace. `System.IO` is the namespace.